# Install tensorflow 1.4.0 on macOS 10.13.1, appear error when run "Hello Tensorflow"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow, I used pip to install tensorflow, the result:

```
Installing collected packages: tensorflow
Successfully installed tensorflow-1.4.0
```

next I try to run the example "hello tensorflow"

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

the result:

```
import tensorflow as tf  
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')  
sess = tf.Session()  
2017-11-23 17:22:38.024094: I 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports 
instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: 
SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA  
print(sess.run(hello))  
Hello, TensorFlow!
```

HELP!

Answer (score 2):

**It's not an error but a warning.** So you do not have to worry about it

Basically says that Tensorflow does not make the most of your CPUs because it has not been configured for that.

The solution is to [install it from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources)

Comment: I use virtualenv to install, error "-bash: virtualenv: command not found",how to solve?

Comment: if appear the question, I must use install it from source, can I install from virtualenv?

Comment: sorry, there are not enough people use tensorflow on macOS in China, so I can not find the answer